# I forgot the password I entered during PostgreSQL installation

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, forgot-password

I either forgot or mistyped (during the installation) the password to the default user of PostgreSQL. I can't seem to be able to run it, and I get the following error:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "hisham"
hisham-agil: hisham$ psql
```

Is there a way to reset the password or how do I create a new user with superuser privileges?

I am new to PostgreSQL and just installed it for the first time. I am trying to use it with Ruby on Rails and I am running [Mac OS X v10.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Lion) (Lion).

Comment: I cannot comment on answers yet, so have to do it this way. I did what SaiyanGirl said, however I still needed to enter a password, which was 'postgres' to log in, then I could reset the password

Answer (score 461, accepted):

1. Find the file *pg_hba.conf*. It may be located, for example, in */etc/postgresql-9.1/pg_hba.conf*.

   `cd /etc/postgresql-9.1/`
2. Back it up

   `cp pg_hba.conf pg_hba.conf-backup`
3. Place the following line (as either the first uncommented line, or as the only one):

   > For all occurrence of below (local and host) , except replication
   > section if you don't have any it has to be changed as follow ,no MD5
   > or Peer authentication should be present.

   local  all   all   trust
4. Restart your PostgreSQL server (e.g., on Linux:)

   `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`

   If the service (daemon) doesn't start reporting in log file:

   > local connections are not supported by this build

   you should change

   `local  all   all   trust`

   to

   `host  all   all  127.0.0.1/32  trust`
5. You can now connect as any user. Connect as the superuser *postgres* (note, *the superuser name may be different in your installation. In some systems it is called *pgsql*, for example.*)

   `psql -U postgres`

   or

   `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres`

   (note that with the first command you will not always be connected with local host)
6. Reset the password ('replace my_user_name with **postgres** since you are resetting the **postgres** user)

   `ALTER USER my_user_name with password 'my_secure_password';`
7. Restore the old *pg_hba.conf* file as it is **very dangerous** to keep around

   `cp pg_hba.conf-backup pg_hba.conf`
8. Restart the server, in order to run with the safe *pg_hba.conf* file

   `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`

*Further reading* about that pg_hba file: *[19.1. The pg_hba.conf File](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)* (official documentation)

Comment: That's pretty much it. If possible, do this at the console and disconnect your machine from the network while you do this to avoid someone hacking it while you work.

Comment: And then start `psql`? I'm still getting prompted for a password, and I do not know it

Comment: Worked great thanks! Note: Keep pgAdmin closed while following these steps.

Comment: this answer did NOT work for me, after I do step 3, the service won´t start, I don´t know, maybe it´s the OS(W8), it just won´t.

Comment: anyone for Windows?

Comment: @Mahesha999: it's the same for Windows. Except that you need `net stop ...` and `net start ...` or the Control Panel to stop and start the service (and you can not use `local` connections in Windows)

Comment: this command is not working for me      local  all   all   trust

Comment: Keep in mind order of entries in pg_hba.conf is important. If you add "local all all trust" to the end of the file, it'll not work as you expect, as previous records will be matched first. So put that at the top of the file to have what you expect.

Comment: If you're on windows with this error, keep scrolling to @SaiyanGirl 's answer. Just modfiy the METHOD columns of the existing entries to 'trust', then change it back when you're done

Comment: `psql -U postgres` will simply log in if not then you can use password that you have provided at installation time.

Comment: I also had to add `local   all             postgres                                trust` to `/etc/postgresql/9.5/mainpg_hba.conf`.

Comment: You should comment all other lines or replace all `md5` with `trust`.

Comment: This failed for me until I finally set the IPv6 from md5 to trust. I had thought it was ignoring that and only using IPv4. Apparently not. Perhaps removing the IPv6 line entirely would also have worked.

Comment: I found the `pg_hba.conf` file in `/Library/PostgreSQL/11/data` (MacOS v.10 and postgress v.11)

Comment: I found that the easiest way to find the file for mac is `find / -name 'pg_hba.conf' 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: I'm being asked for postgres password at step 2, same password ive forgotten, how do I go about it now?

Comment: LOL, I've just spent an extra 30 minutes on this because I forgot to add a semicolon to the end of the SQL query

Comment: Just instead of `md5` need set `scram-sha-256` - for Postgres 14 / Ubuntu 22

Comment: @CodyBugstein and anyone who is still prompted to enter password, I have solved it just by closing  putty (I am accessing ubuntu using putty) and reconnecting.

Answer (score 155):

When connecting to PostgreSQL from the command line, don't forget to add `-h localhost` as a command line parameter. If not, PostgreSQL will try to connect using PEER authentication mode.

The below shows a reset of the password, a failed login with PEER authentication and a successful login using a TCP connection.

```
# sudo -u postgres psql

could not change directory to "/root"
psql (9.1.11)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \password
Enter new password:
Enter it again:
postgres=# \q
```

Failing:

```
# psql -U postgres -W

Password for user postgres:
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Working with `-h localhost`:

```
# psql -U postgres -W  -h localhost

Password for user postgres:
psql (9.1.11)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Comment: Unneeded on Windows cmd.exe

Answer (score 88):

The `pg_hba.conf` (`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data`) file has changed since these answers were given. What worked for me, in Windows, was to open the file and change the `METHOD` from `md5` to `trust`:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Then, using [pgAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#Database_administration) III, I logged in without using a password and changed user `postgres`'s password by going to menu *File* → *Change Password*.

Comment: This doesn't work because PgAdmin still asks for the current password... I reset to 'trust' and restarted PgAdmin. Still can't reset without typing in the CURRENT password...

Comment: Once you change the method to `trust` you can follow [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-alteruser.html) and alter password in cmd

Comment: **Interesting note:** Running PostgreSQL Server 13 on Windows, even after making the aforementioned changes, the server will still prompt for a password when trying to connect (when using pgAdmin). You can just hit "OK" (w/o specifying a password) and the server will let you in. I did not anticipate being prompted.

Comment: Just to add to the above interesting note, I had to click "Cancel"; clicking "Okay" just got another demand for a password. And whenever I tried to actually do anything, I got a further demand, so it was not much help.

Comment: In my case the file was in `C:\Users\user\Documents\PostgreSQL\13\data`.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, windows 11 user here. I logged into PgAdmin and selected the database

Answer (score 31):

###### For Windows (what has helped me):

This is the document I am referring to: *[How can I reset a PostgreSQL password?](https://qsartoolbox.org/content/documents/ResettingPostgreSQLPassword.pdf)*

1. Open your cmd and go to `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data`.
   This is usually the right path. You might have it stored somewhere else. Note that, if you have a different PostgreSQL version, there will be a different number. That doesn't matter.
2. Find a **pg_hba.conf** file and copy it to somewhere else (that way you will have an unmodified version of this file, so you will be able to look at it after we make some changes)
3. Open the *pg_hba.conf* file (not the backup, but the original)
4. Find the multiple lines that start with host near the bottom of the file:

   ```
   host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

   host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

   host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

   host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
   ```
5. Replace **md5** with **trust**:

   ```
   host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

   host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust

   host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

   host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
   ```
6. Close this file
7. Go to your search bar on windows and open **Services** app. Find *postgres* and restart it.

   [Picture of services app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jByFn.png)
8. Write *cd..* in cmd and then *cd bin*. Your path should be `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin`
9. Enter: `psql -U postgres -h localhost`
10. Enter: `ALTER USER postgres with password '<your new password>';`**Make sure that you include ; at the end**
    “ALTER ROLE” should be displayed as an indication that the previous line was executed successfully
11. Open original *pg_hba.conf* file and change back from trust to md5
12. Restart the server with Services app as before

Comment: `psql -U postgres -h localhost` -> `.\psql.exe -U postgres -h localhost`

Answer (score 23):

1. Edit the file `/etc/postgresql/<version>/main/pg_hba.conf` and find the following line:

   ```
   local  all  postgres  md5
   ```
2. Edit the line and change `md5` at the end to `trust` and save the file
3. Reload the **postgresql** service

   ```
   sudo service postgresql reload
   ```
4. This will load the configuration files. Now you can modify the `postgres` user by logging into the `psql` shell

   ```
   psql -U postgres
   ```
5. Update the `postgres` user's password

   ```
   alter user postgres with password 'secure-passwd-here';
   ```
6. Edit the file `/etc/postgresql/<version>/main/pg_hba.conf` and change `trust` back to `md5` and save the file
7. Reload the **postgresql** service

   ```
   sudo service postgresql reload
   ```
8. Verify that the password change is working

   ```
   psql -U postgres -W
   ```

Comment: Is it so hard to give a Windows solution? Not everyone uses Linux with sudo. How would I do it on Windows??

Comment: Just instead of `md5` need set `scram-sha-256` - for Postgres 14 / Ubuntu 22

Answer (score 23):

I was just having this problem on Windows 10 and the issue in my case was that I was just running `psql` and it was defaulting to trying to log in with my Windows username ("Nathan"), but there was no PostgreSQL user with that name, and it wasn't telling me that.

So the solution was to run `psql -U postgres` rather than just `psql`, and then the password I entered at installation worked.

Answer (score 17):

Just a note: On Linux, you can simply run `sudo su - postgres` to become the *postgres* user and from there change what is required using *psql*.

Comment: you still need the password after running psql

Answer (score 8):

For a Windows user for the latest PostgreSQL version (greater than 10):

Go to your PostgreSQL installation location, and search for `pg_hba.conf`, you will find it in `..\postgres\data\pg_hba.conf`.

Open that file with [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29), and find this line:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
#..

Change the method from *md5* to *trust*:

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# ...
```

Now go to your SQL shell (PSQL) and leave everything blank,

```
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [8000]:
Username [postgres]:
```

It will not ask for a password this time, and you will be logged in,

Now run this line:

```
  `ALTER USER yourusername WITH SUPERUSER`
```

Now you can leave the shell with *\q*.

Again, go to the file *pg_hba.conf* and change *METHOD* from *trust* to *md5* again, and save it.

Now log in with your new user and password, and you can check \du for its attributes.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running PostgreSQL on [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS), try [these](http://cli23.blogspot.com/2013/12/resetting-postgresql-postgres-user.html):

**1. Edit the *pg_hba.conf* file**

`sudo vi /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data/pg_hba.conf`
and Change the "md5" method for all users to "trust" near the bottom of the file

**2. Find the name of the postgres service**

`ls /Library/LaunchDaemons`
Look for *postgresql*

**3. Restart the *postgresql* service**

`sudo launchctl stop com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.2`

`sudo launchctl start com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.2` *(com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.2 should be name postgresql service from step 3)*

**4. Start a *psql* session as *postgres***
`psql -U postgres`
*(shouldn't ask for password because of 'trust' setting)*

**5. Reset password in the psql session by typing:**

```
    ALTER USER postgres with password 'secure-new-password';
```

**6. Edit the *pg_hba.conf* file**
Switch it back to 'md5'

**8. Restart services again**

Answer (score 2):

For a Windows installation, a Windows user is created. And "psql" uses this user for connection to the port. If you change the PostgreSQL user's password, it won't change the Windows one.
The command line just below works only if you have access to the command line.

Instead, you could use the Windows GUI application "c:\Windows\system32\lusrmgr.exe". This application manages users created by Windows. So you can now modify the password.

Comment: But not for [Windows 10 Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions#Baseline_editions)?

Comment: What is the name of the application? *Local User And Group Management*?

Answer (score 2):

I did this to resolve the same problem:

Open the *pg_hba.conf* file with the [gedit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedit) editor from the terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
```

It will ask for a password. Enter your admin login password.
This will open gedit with the file. Paste the following line:

```
host  all   all  127.0.0.1/32  trust
just below -

# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
```

Save and close it.

Close the terminal, open it again and run this command:

```
psql -U postgres
```

You will now enter the *psql* console.

Now change the password by entering this:

```
ALTER USER [your preferred user name] with password '[desired password]';
```

If it says the user does not exist then instead of `ALTER`, use `CREATE`.

Lastly, remove that certain line you pasted in *pg_hba* and save it.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -u postgres psql

ALTER USER user_name WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows you can just run

```
net user postgres postgres
```

And log in in PostgreSQL with *postgres/postgres* as the user/password.

Answer (score 0):

Follow step 1 on the best answer.

Here is my addition if you use the Windows operating system. Follow only step 1, and then open [pgAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#Database_administration) or postgres on web and click on file on the top nav. Click on reset layout, and finally reload the application. Whatever password you put should work. I used *1234*.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to find the file `pg_hba.conf` in the folder `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data`, because there is not a folder `data` at all.

I solved the problem by creating a new user using [pgAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#Database_administration) and gave it super system administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your PostgreSQL installation location, and search for pg_hba.conf, you will find it in ..\postgres\data\pg_hba.conf.
2. open your notepad
3. Now go to your SQL shell (PSQL) and leave everything blank
4. It will not ask for a password this time, and you will be logged in and now run this line,
   `ALTER USER yourusername WITH SUPERUSER`
5. go to the file pg_hba.conf and change METHOD from trust to md5 again, and save it which was open your notepad.

Answer (score 0):

If your postgres is running in a docker container, try the following line instead:

```
host    all             all             172.17.0.1/32            trust
```

`172.17.0.1` is the gateway address for the docker bridge network.

Answer (score -1):

Add the below line to your *pg_hba.conf* file. Which will be present in the installation directory of PostgreSQL

```
hostnossl    all          all            0.0.0.0/0  trust
```

It will start working.