# Change/reset postgresql user password on windows 7

Tags: postgresql, windows-7

Several days ago  I install postgesql 9.2 version on my local computer. (OS windows 7)

Now I forgot my password and I can not login in pgAdmin.

How to change postgresql password on windows 7?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845998/i-forgot-the-password-i-entered-during-postgres-installation which has a more explanitive answer ;)

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44586/forgotten-postgresql-windows-password

Comment: Check this link: [forgotten-postgresql-windows-password](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44586/forgotten-postgresql-windows-password) **It is work for me**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit `pg_hba.conf` to allow you to connect without a password. Then use ALTER USER to reset the password. Then change pg_hba.conf back again.

For the documentation on pg_hba.conf, see here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Edit how? I have no idea what to put or remove from that file.

Comment: @klerik, the link is to the manual page for pg_hba.conf. It explains everything about pg_hba.conf.

Comment: Note that in Windows the `pg_hba.con` file is under the `data` folder, e.g. `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data`

Comment: Still get an error even after making a new password

Comment: Very bad explained answer. I don't know how it got 14 votes.

Comment: How does one edit the pg_hba.conf  file to allow you to connect without a password? The explanation was very vague and am not sure how it got the upvotes.

Answer (score 55):

In the `pg_hba.conf` file, change (temporarily) all `METHOD` with `trust`. EG :

```
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

instead of :

```
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

You can find where the `pg_hba.conf` is located by typing in a psql command line:

```
SHOW hba_file;
```

Comment: Dont forget to restart service

Answer (score 20):

Below steps helped me to reset the password-

1. Go to `pg_hba.conf` file at path e.g. `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data` and add below line at the end,

   ```
   host all postgres 127.0.0.1/32 trust
   ```
2. Restart the PostgreSQL service from services control panel (start -> run -> services.msc)
3. Connect using PgAdmin or any software that you prefer and run query,

   ```
   ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'postgres'
   ```
4. Remove the line that you added in step 1.
5. Restart PostgreSQL.

Comment: I was able to loging using My SQL and run: ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD myPassword. Do I need the ''? Because it didn't work. What worked for me was to login using pgAdmin4 and change inside the server config. After resenting the pg_hba the new password worked.

Comment: I think you should replace the "host xxx md5" line. Only adding did not worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I am using postgres version 14.0 and Windows 10. To reset the password:

1. I opened the windows command prompt and typed: psql -U postgres(postgres is my username)
2. Type in your current password

3 Then type: \password postgres

[image]

It brings up the prompts to type the new password and confirm. Note for the psql command to work on the windows command prompt, you need to set the postgres bin folder on the path environment variable. You can just google how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Run your psql executable file and login into your database using your old password, use the following command to login:

```
 .\psql.exe -U postgres
```

Then use

```
ALTER USER <user_name> WITH PASSWORD <'new_password'>
```

For more information refer this link : 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/sql-alteruser.html

Comment: IF you can still login (hence haven't forgotten your password), this is probably the easiest and most save.

Answer (score 2):

In windows postgres stores password for automatic login at following path 
(only if you would have selected password save option while installation)

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf

you can open this file in a text editor and see your password.

Comment: I wasn't able to find this file nor the `postgresql` folder in my Roaming folder though.

Comment: thank you, I was able to find the file 'pgpass.conf' in another user's folder