# Can't remember my postgres user password to connect server

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm working in this Django app but I stopped working on it per two weeks, so my computer was off during this time. Now I want to work on it again this error appear to me over and over again in my command line, I opened pgAdmin and found is because I need my password for my postgres user and I can't remember it. Does anybody knows how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: your error says nothing on authentication. it looks postgres cluster is not running - just start it.

Answer (score 1):

The postgres account has no password (by default).
You should not be using this account to connect to the database.
If you are using a linux distribution, you can execute the following command in order to create another user account that you can use for login:

> sudo -u postgres psql -c "create user newuser with superuser password
>   'new_password_123';"

This way you will create a user with username `newuser` and password `new_password_123`

There is also another way to reset the password that is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587710/change-reset-postgresql-user-password-on-windows-7) question.

Comment: I tried that way and obtained: 

Password:
could not identify current directory: Permission denied
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: Are you sure that your postgresql server is running ?

Comment: Yes, my server was running but I can't find what happened so I had to create another DB.