# Null password failing login for postgres 9.3 windows

Tags: sql, windows, postgresql, null, passwords

I changed the postgres password to NULL for the user postgres on my local machine. using the following command in SQL window:
ALTER ROLE postgres WITH PASSWORD NULL;

Now, I cannot login back again as it asking for password and not accepting anything. I can't run the SQL query to change the password as I am not logged in now. Can I do something from windows command prompt to change the password back?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/19643/7788, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10845998/398670 .

Comment: PostgreSQL could possibly stop you doing this if it sees that your `pg_hba.conf` has `trust` authentication, but it doesn't know you're not doing it on purpose (say, after creating another superuser).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit `pg_hba.conf` file to enable `trust` (no password) auth-method for `localhost`. Details here:http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Adding

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

to the start of the `pg_hba.conf` file will enable no-password login from `127.0.0.1/32` (localhost)

Comment: I tried to change the text in config file list this: localhost:5432:*:postgres:trust <br/> but this does not work. Is something wrong with it? Also tried localhost:5432:*:postgres:iden but this is also not working.

Comment: Format of your string is not the one that `pg_hba.conf` needs. try the string I posted in the answer. After the change to `pg_hba.conf` - restart the server.

Comment: I edited the the lines at the bottom of the file like this and now it works. Thanks for your help:                               # IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust

Comment: @user3789876 Do not forget to remove the line after you fixed the login.

Answer (score 3):

First go to the pg_hba.conf file and open it in any editor (notepad or notepad++).

Location of *pg_hba.conf* is mainly

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data
```

Change method  as md5 to trust

```
#TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Instead of

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

then save it.

Run Command prompt as administrator and goto

`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin`

directory through cmd.

Run reload postgres service command

```
pg_ctl.exe reload -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data"
```

Got to PgAdmin and connect localhost database without using password

[image: Start pgadmin]

Go to the properties

[image: Open properties]

Change the password in Definition tab

[image: Change password]

Then again change method trust to md5 .

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Again Run reload postgres service command

```
pg_ctl.exe reload -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data"
```