# How to ensure data security even if postgres data can be accessed

Tags: postgresql

I am installing postgres along side a intranet application. The data folder of postgres can be accessed by the user. I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845998/i-forgot-the-password-i-entered-during-postgres-installation) how one can reset the postgres user password and thus compromising data security.

Am I correct in understanding pg_hba.conf is data specific?
Is it possible to lock down modifications to pg_hba.conf or hard code the configuration somewhere so that one cant follow the steps described to the question linked above?

Comment: `The data folder of postgres can be accessed by the user.` It shouldn't. Avoid shell access to the machine. (except for the postgres superuser) And dont give away the postgres account to mortals.

Comment: can using an on the fly encryption/decryption platform help in restricting the user from accessing the data? How big will be the performance dips