# Forgot Postgres 9.5 Password, Reinstalling not working

Tags: postgresql

I believe I set a password when I first installed it, but can't remember what it was. So I've tried reinstalling it, but it never asked to set password and it still wont let me connect.

And I've looked at the pgpass.conf file, but it's empty.

I can't seem to find a clear answer on how to solve this from older posts on this topic.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks

Comment: What OS where PostgreSQL installed?

Comment: Check [I forgot the password I entered during postgres installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845998/i-forgot-the-password-i-entered-during-postgres-installation). You basically need to alter a `pg_hba.conf` and connect to the DB *without* password, then set it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...im on windows 10