# Superuser expired and is the only user

Tags: postgresql, database-connection

I'm using Postgres 9.5 on Windows 7.

I have only one user `postgres` and I defined an expiry date for that user.

Now I'm trying to connect after is expired and I can't, so does anyone know how
to cancel the expiry from the superuser, so I don't have to reinstall Postgres.

I tried to edit `pg_hba.conf` to allow `trust` for `postgres` but still the same problem.

Comment: [I forgot the password I entered during postgres installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10845998/1995738)

Comment: but i cannot connect using command psql -U postgres

Comment: Read the accepted answer.

Comment: try peer auth - dont specify postgres. just `sudo su - postgres` and then `psql`

Comment: i'm using windows forget to mentioned that sorry

Comment: @klin: This way you can circumvent password authentication, but I don't think it can circumvent an expired `VALID UNTIL ....` setting for a given role.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - your tip is helpful I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start the server in single-user mode to fix the faulty "expiry date" with:

```
ALTER ROLE postgres VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-postgres.html)

> The `postgres` command [...]
>   When invoked in single-user mode from the shell, the user can
>   enter queries and the results will be printed to the screen, but in a
>   form that is more useful for developers than end users. In the
>   single-user mode, **the session user will be set to the user with ID 1,
>   and implicit superuser powers are granted to this user. This user
>   does not actually have to exist**, so the single-user mode can be used
>   to manually recover from certain kinds of accidental damage to the
>   system catalogs.

Bold emphasis mine.

Aside: It's a pretty "creative" idea to let the superuser `postgres` expire. IOW: **don't**.

Comment: Looks right i will give it a try i just tried this to see if the super user can be expired thanks

Comment: just one question when i ran this using cmd window in adminstration mode didn't allow this. i used the git bash shell and it worked fine. do you have any idea

Comment: ok it's fine i used with cmd without administration privelage and it worked fine. thank you