# How to map user to database in postgresql, change password[WINDOWS]

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data

I have following spring boot configuration:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/study-designer-dev
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=sa
```

But when I start my application I see:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

But I am sure that I typed `sa` password for default(I thinks it is `postgres`) user

[image]

I don't see menu where I can change password, map user to database and so on.

Please clarify how can I do this ?

P.S.

I have seen [this link](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/change_password_dialog.html) but I have not idea how to ask pgadmin show this dialog

Comment: have a look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html **especially example 19.1**

Comment: try a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845998/i-forgot-the-password-i-entered-during-postgres-installation

Comment: Where can I type commands like**psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres**

Comment: if windows then open a command/dos prompt

Comment: `alter user ... with password ...` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alteruser.html

Comment: @Scary Wombat can you clarify folder path?

Comment: Are you really asking me how to find a file on windows?  Also I think yiou can open this file from pgadmin