# How to reset postgres password

Tags: postgresql, wamp

I am on Windows 10 using WAMP, I added PostgreSQL and PhpPgAdmin, everything was working fine.  Today I can not log in to PostgreSQL through PhpPgAdmin or a php_pdo web app.

I tried editing `pg_hba.conf` in 2 locations `c:\PostgreSQL\pg96\init\` and `c:\PostgreSQL\data\pg96\` and changed the 'method' to `trust` as per many answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845998/i-forgot-the-password-i-entered-during-postgres-installation), none of the CLI answers worked either.

I also restarted "WAMP" and even the whole computer, but no luck.

The default password worked before `postgres` and `root` but not now.

How do I reset the postgre password?

UPDATE

runing `psql -U postgres` returns;

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

contents of `pg_hba.conf`

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            CIDR-ADDRESS            METHOD

# IPv4 local & remote connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after a lot more diging, it was not that the password was wrong, but for whatever reason PostgreSQL was not even running.  *Windows is such a PITA!*

in the end, running `pg_ctl -D "C:\PostgreSQL\data\pg96" start` from CMD got it going.  Now we will see if it starts tomorrow.... I miss my Unix Environment.

#### **----- UPDATE -----**

While the above code works, it is moving in the wrong direction.
goto `Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services` and find 'PostgreSQL ...' in the list.  Right click and open Properties.

My `Startup type:` was set to '**Automatic**' but it was not starting, I set it to '**Automatic (Delayed Start)**' and now it is working, automagically!