# Unable to drop Postgres database

Tags: database, postgresql, psql, database-administration, drop-database

I am learning Postgres and went through the getting started documentation to create a database called `testDb` and a role called `testUser`. The `testDb` database was created with the owner `testUser` using my superuser account `ciesinsg`.

I want to delete `testDb` and `testUser` as I am no longer using them, but I am unable to delete the `testDb` database no matter what I try.

My `\l` and `\du` output is at the very bottom of this question if needed.

## What I've Tried

### DROP DATABASE

First, I tried connecting to my postgres database and running the DROP DATABASE command.

```bash
psql postgres
DROP DATABASE testDb;
```

This outputted `ERROR:  database "testdb" does not exist` even though that is the name when I use `\l`.

### Stack Overflow QA's

I searched through stack overflow for similar issues.

1. [This QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54074017/unable-to-drop-database-in-postgres) advised that only a superuser or owner of the database can delete it, which is what my `ciesinsg` role is. As I understand it, this is the role used to login when I run `psql postgres`.

I tried instead logging in with `psql -U ciesinsg postgres` which worked, but when I ran `DROP DATABASE testDb;` it outputs the same error as before.

2. I found [another QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408156/how-to-drop-a-postgresql-database-if-there-are-active-connections-to-it) which looked promising. This one had an answer that suggested to run:

```bash
sudo service postgresql stop
sudo service postgresql start

psql
DROP DATABASE DB_NAME;
```

On my setup, this looked like:

```bash
brew services stop postgresql@15
brew services start postgresql@15

psql postgres
DROP DATABASE testDb;
```

But this also outputted the same error.

### Login as Owner

Next I tried to login as owner: `psql -U testUser testDb` which worked and it showed `testDb=>` where it expects new commands.

I tried:

```bash
testDb=> DROP DATABASE testDb;
```

which outputs:

```bash
testDb=> DROP DATABASE testDb;
ERROR:  database "testdb" does not exist
```

### Using PGAdmin4

So next, I referred to [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58894875/how-to-delete-a-database-in-pgadmin) and tried to use PGAdmin4 to delete it. Unfortunately, the check mark is greyed out beside `testDb` so I was unable to select it for deletion.

[image]

### Successful Solution

I am updating this with the solution that worked, but I am keeping the question open to understand why all of my other solutions failed.

After much searching, I found [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073773/how-to-drop-postgresql-database-through-command-line) which recommended to run `dropdb 'database_name'`. I tried this but it said one client was still accessing the database, so I ran:

```bash
brew services stop postgresql@15
brew services start postgresql@15
dropdb 'testDb'
```

After running `\l` I saw it was finally deleted.

## Conclusion

After referring to the documentation, stack overflow, and trying numerous solutions, the only one that worked was the `dropdb` command.

I want to understand why all of the other methods I attempted failed as I was following documentation and answers. I want to know what I was doing wrong.

## Database and Role

My output for `\l` and `\du` is below

```bash
postgres-# \l
                                                List of databases
    Name    |     Owner      | Encoding | Collate | Ctype | ICU Locale | Locale Provider |   Access privileges
------------+----------------+----------+---------+-------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------
 itsGallery | itsGalleryUser | UTF8     | C       | C     |            | libc            |
 postgres   | ciesinsg       | UTF8     | C       | C     |            | libc            |
 template0  | ciesinsg       | UTF8     | C       | C     |            | libc            | =c/ciesinsg          +
            |                |          |         |       |            |                 | ciesinsg=CTc/ciesinsg
 template1  | ciesinsg       | UTF8     | C       | C     |            | libc            | =c/ciesinsg          +
            |                |          |         |       |            |                 | ciesinsg=CTc/ciesinsg
 testDb     | testUser       | UTF8     | C       | C     |            | libc            |
(5 rows)

postgres-# \du
                                      List of roles
   Role name    |                         Attributes                         | Member of
----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 ciesinsg       | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 itsGalleryUser | Create role, Create DB, Replication                        | {}
 testUser       | Create DB                                                  | {}
```

## Additional Info

- Macbook Pro M2 with Ventura 13.4.1
- Postgresql@15 and PGAdmin4 installed using homebrew
- The Homebrew formula sets my `ciesinsg` user up as a superuser, so there is no `postgres` user/role to my knowledge
- testDb and testUser created using CLI when learning to use Postgres
- PGAdmin4 connected to the database afterwards, so not prior to initial creation of database or user
- I am new to Postgres and still trying to learn the basics

Comment: The linked question is about columns, but the same applies to databases.

Comment: I see, so if I understand it correctly, I must have created the database with quotation marks so now I need to use quotation marks when running commands to drop the database?

Comment: Yes, precisely, you got it. The best thing is to avoid quoted identifiers altogether, then you will never have that problem.