# How to reset PostgreSQL password

Tags: postgresql, change-password, forgot-password

I had downloaded PostgreSQL unknowingly and I don't know the password now, how can I find it out or how to change it?
Do I have to re-install it?
Please Help

Edit: I'm using a windows os

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I forgot the password I entered during postgres installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845998/i-forgot-the-password-i-entered-during-postgres-installation)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Reinforcement the pg_dba.conf record by replicating it to an alternate area or simply rename it to pg_dba_bk.conf

Step 2. Alter the pg_dba.conf document by including the accompanying line as the primary line after the remark lines. The remark line begins with the # sign.

```
local  all   all   trust

host    all              postgres           127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

Step 3. Restart PostgreSQL server e.g., in Linux, you use the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Step 4. Connect to PostgreSQL database server.

```
psql -U postgres
```

Step 5. change the password of the postgres user.

```
ALTER USER postgres with password 'very_secure_password';
```

Step 6. Restore the pg_db.conf file and restart the server, and connect to the PostgreSQL database server with new password.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Comment: do you mean `ph_hba.conf` not `pg_dba.conf`?