# PostgreSQL service cannot start on Manjaro?

Tags: postgresql, manjaro

I want to run postgresql in manjaro by the following command.

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

And i got the following result.

```
Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xeu postgresql.service" for details.
```

The log was as follow.

```
Jul 29 17:22:43 mahyar-pc postgres[2078]: "/var/lib/postgres/data" is missing or empty. Use a command like
Jul 29 17:22:43 mahyar-pc postgres[2078]:   su - postgres -c "initdb --locale en_US.UTF-8 -D '/var/lib/postgr>
Jul 29 17:22:43 mahyar-pc postgres[2078]: with relevant options, to initialize the database cluster.
Jul 29 17:22:43 mahyar-pc systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILU>
```

Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to initialize PostgreSQL’s data directory.

From line 2 of the log, you can initialize with `su - postgres -c "initdb --locale en_US.UTF-8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'"`

Comment: the postgres user has default password and I am not to able change it. how can I change it?

Comment: By default, postgres does not require a password for authentication. But perhaps, this could help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21509419/13895621

Comment: It is done! I had to change my su password. Thanks